# How do you show that Lurie's straightening preserves colimits?

Tags: category-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

I am struggling to show that the straightening construction (2.2.1 in Higher Topos Theory) preserves colimits. More specifically let $M_X:=\mathfrak{C}X^\triangleright\sqcup_{\mathfrak{C}X}C^{op}$ for $X\to S$ a simplicial set over $S$ and $\phi\colon\mathfrak{C}S\to C^{op}$ a functor between simplicially enriched categories. If $\infty\in M_X$ denotes the image of the cone point of $\mathfrak{C}X^\triangleright$ and if $i\colon C^{op}\to M_X$ is the inclusion then the straightening of $X$ is defined as $St_\phi  X=map_{M_X}(i(-),\infty)$. Showing that this functor preserves colimits provides us with its right adjoint, the unstraightening.

I can think of two approaches to this:

1. Let $X\colon I\to(Set_{\Delta})_{/S}$ with $i\mapsto X_i$ be a small diagram.
   Then $colim_i(St_\phi X_i)\cong St_\phi(colim_i X_i)$ would follow if we showed that $colim_i M_{X_i}\simeq M_{colim_i X_i}$. The  problem is that the cone functor $X\mapsto X^\triangleright$ only preserves connected colimits and so $M_{(-)}$ probably doesn't preserve small colimits (I think it is not to hard to construct a counterexample by letting $\phi$ be the identity, $S=\Delta^0$ and $X=\Delta^0\sqcup\Delta^0$ be a coproduct of two points).
2. Another appraoch would be to directly construct the unstraightening. We know how this is supposed to look by using our knowledge about a left Kan extension and its right adjoint along the Yoneda embedding. However that the construction we get is really a right adjoint to the straightening defined above is not easy to see and doesn't seem to be the right approach to this problem.

Any hints or thoughts are welcome.

edit: My third approach was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so the answer seems to be easier than I initially thought, because I kept thinking about the straightening of coproducts. A functor preserves all small colimits if and only if it preserves the initial object and [wide pushouts](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/wide+pullback). It is not hard to see that the straightening of the empty simplicial set is the functor $C\to Set_{\Delta}$ that is constant on the empty set. Now joins and in particular the functor $-\star\Delta^0$ preserve connected colimits (as an endofunctor on $Set_\Delta$). Since pushouts and $\mathfrak{C}$ commute with colimits we deduce that the assignment $X\mapsto M_X$ preserves wide pushouts (because they are always connected). Thus straightening also preserves wide pushouts. This proves the claim.